# Using Google Maps controls for a large image

Tags: google-maps

I have large images that I would like to have dragging and zooming controls like Google Maps. I started looking into Google Maps API and some other related websites, but I could not find something simple and easy.

MapKi tutorial suggests me to [automatically cut tiles](http://mapki.com/wiki/Automatic_Tile_Cutter) and [add it as a custom map](http://mapki.com/wiki/Add_Your_Own_Custom_Map). This makes sense, but I have so many images in the file server that I don't have time to go through all of them and cut the tiles and figure out zoom levels for each. One good solution would be writing a script that can do this automatically, but that would take a lot of effort and time that has made to look for another solution if there is any.

Hence, is there a way to have similar functionalities as Google Maps controls for images without creating new images or tiles out of the original image. It would be great if you can either post some code or link to the tutorial/documentation. Or, if you know how to do this with Google API without making those tiles, please direct me to the right path. I'm a total newbie with Google Maps API.

I have found the [DragZoom](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/08/you-can-always-go-back-to-where-you.html) for Google Maps, but I don't think that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like [Djatoka](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djatoka)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the IIIF protocol used by libraries and museums for zooming extremely large images (tens of thousands of pixels on a side +), preparing collections of images on canvases, presenting annotations on those images, etc.

http://iiif.io

Answer (score 0):

…and just for the record here's an open source tiling server with a frontend viewer:

http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/Murtnowski/GMap-JSlicer

```
slicer = new JSlicer(document.getElementById('map'), 'myImage.png');
slicer.init();
```

It's super simple, no need for tile pre-cutting.  Just point at a single image and go.